# Como verificar se o arquivo txt tem um espaço em branco na última linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

eu tenho um script aqui que procura todos os arquivos .txt de uma pasta e depois junta eles em um arquivo só.

O problema é que alguns arquivos possuem um "\n" na última linha, fazendo com que a próxima linha não fique em baixo da anterior, causando erros quando eu importo o .txt final.

Seria possível fazer um check para verificar se a última linha de um arquivo tem um "\n" e assim deletar ele e se não tiver, adicionar um "\n".

Os meus aquivos estão nesse formato:

```
00000011098720150131379000100011
00000021098720150131379000400011
00000021098720150131379000400011
```

Aqui está o código:

```
import os
import glob

found = False
source_folder = None

while not found:
  source_folder = str(input("Adicione o diretório com os arquivos.))
   print(source_folder)
  if not os.path.isdir(source_folder):
    print(source_folder, 'A pasta não foi encontrada.)
else:
    print("Pasta encontrada! ")
    found = True

os.chdir(source_folder)

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
print(read_files)

arq = str(input("Adicione o nome do arquivo: "))

with open(arq, "wb") as outfile:
  for f in read_files:
      with open(f, "rb") as infile:
          outfile.write(infile.read())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito simples, já que você lê os arquivos anteriores todos como uma única string, é usar o método `strip` que remove todos caractéres de espaço do começo e do final da string.

Com isso, linhas em branco no final serão removidas, mas também o `\n` após a última linha, que é necessário - por isso adicionamos ele de volta.

Bom, tudo isso pra dizer que você só precisa re-escrever esta linha:

```
outfile.write(infile.read())
```

deixando a assim:

```
outfile.write(infile.read().strip() + "\n")
```

Se as linhas em branco estivessem no meio do arquivo, em vez de no final, seria necessário iterar linha por linha e eliminar as em branco. Graças as comprehensions do Python isso poderia ficar numa linha só também:

```
outfile.writelines(line for line in infile if line.strip())
```

Só isso: o método `writelines` espera um iterador, que é a generator expression entre parenteses. O `for` dessa expression, por sua vez, usa o arquivo de entrada como um iterador, pegando linha por linha  - e a expressão de filtro, depois do `if` descarta as linhas em branco: se a linha tiver só espaços e o `\n`, o strip a transforma numa string vazia, que tem valor booleano falso, e aí ela é descartada do gerador.

Comment: jsbueno, muito obrigado por usar o seu tempo para me responder.

Poderia me ajudar com mais uma coisa?  Quando eu coloco "outfile.write(infile.read().strip() + "\n")", ele apenas cria o arquivo mas ele fica vazio.(no pycharm, aparece: "expected type 'bytes', bot 'str' instead"
Quando eu uso "outfile.writelines(line for line in infile if line.strip())" ele faz tudo certo, mas quando muda de arquivo, ele não deixa o "/n", saberia me dizer o que eu teria que fazer para arrumar isso?

Desculpa caso a solução seja óbvia, mas comecei a estudar python no começo da semana, então estou bem perdido

Comment: Tudo certo! depois de algumas pesquisas, eu consegui achar a solução. 
A linha acabou ficando assim: "outfile.write(infile.read().strip() + b"\n")". 
 Mais uma vez, muito obrigado por me ajudar! @jsbueno

Comment: Nem tinha notado que vocẽ tinha colocado o "b" para abrir o arquivo. O "b" é para arquivos binários - e vai dar um MONTE de coisa errada, por que o Python trata de forma completamente diferente.Se você está lendo texto, tem que abrir como arquivo texto.

Answer (score 0):

Se a intenção é trabalhar com arquivos texto, não tem motivo abrir os arquivos de entrada e saída em modo binário.

Segue uma solução testada capaz de "concatenar" todos os arquivos com extensão `.txt` contidos em um dado diretório em um único  arquivo, ignorando as linhas em branco:

```
import os
import glob

source_folder = input("Entre com o diretorio de origem: ")

try:
    os.chdir(source_folder)
except FileNotFoundError:
    print( "Diretorio nao encontrado: '%s'" % (source_folder) )
    exit(1)

read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
print(read_files)

arq = str(input("Entre com o nome do arquivo de saida: "))

with open(arq, "w") as outfile:             # Abre arquivo de saída para gravacao... 
    for f in read_files:                    # Para cada arquivo de entrada...
        with open(f, "r") as infile:        # Abre arquivo de entrada para leitura...
            for ln in infile:               # Para cada linha do arquivo de entrada..
                if ln.strip().strip("\n"):  # Verifica linha em branco
                    outfile.write(ln)       # Grava linha na saida
```

**arquivo1.txt**

```
00000011098720150131379000101528
00000011098720150131379000101561
00000011098720150131379000101594
00000011098720150131379000101627

00000011098720150131379000101660
00000011098720150131379000101693
00000011098720150131379000101726
00000011098720150131379000101759

00000011098720150131379000101792
00000011098720150131379000101825
00000011098720150131379000101858
```

**arquivo2.txt**

```
00000011098720150131379000108227
00000011098720150131379000108260
00000011098720150131379000108293

00000011098720150131379000108326
00000011098720150131379000108359
00000011098720150131379000108392
00000011098720150131379000108425
```

Testando:

```
$ python3 teste.py 
Entre com o diretorio de origem: /tmp
['arquivo1.txt', 'arquivo2.txt']
Entre com o nome do arquivo de saida: saida.txt
```

**saída.txt**

```
00000011098720150131379000101528
00000011098720150131379000101561
00000011098720150131379000101594
00000011098720150131379000101627
00000011098720150131379000101660
00000011098720150131379000101693
00000011098720150131379000101726
00000011098720150131379000101759
00000011098720150131379000101792
00000011098720150131379000101825
00000011098720150131379000101858
00000011098720150131379000108227
00000011098720150131379000108260
00000011098720150131379000108293
00000011098720150131379000108326
00000011098720150131379000108359
00000011098720150131379000108392
00000011098720150131379000108425
```

Comment: Wow! O código ficou muito limpo dessa forma. Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda @Lacobus.